# I have a problem with clearTimeout, there are few instances in which is not working

Tags: javascript, settimeout, cleartimeout

So the thing is clearTimeout works most of the time just fine, but there are sometimes when it doesnt. First i call the function, at the end of the function there is a setTimeout to call the function again a start looping, and there is a button to clear the timeout which as i already said works just fine most of the time. The code is something like this. The counter reflected in the console lets me see visually when the function is running and when it gets stopped.

EDIT: i already have it like this clearTimeout(foo_timeout), i writed it wrong sorry.

```
var cons = 0

function foo(
  //do some asyncajaxstuff
  cons = cons++
  console.log(cons)
  foo_timeout = setTimeout(foo, 1200);
)

foo()

$("#unsettimeout").click(function(){
  clearTimeout(foo_timeout)
 })
```

Comment: The call should look like `clearTimeout(foo_timeout)`

Comment: You will also want to add `var foo_timeout` under `var cons` since it is a local variable the way you have it set up

Answer (score 0):

Well you example shows clearly `clearTimeout` would never work. You should pass as param returned handler from `setTimeout`.

```js
var cons = 0;
var foo_timeout = null;

function foo() {

  cons = cons + 1;
  console.log(cons);

  foo_timeout = setTimeout(foo, 1200);
}

foo();

$("#unsettimeout").click(function() {
  clearTimeout(foo_timeout);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="unsettimeout">Unset Timeout</button>
```